# Why doesn't my HTML index link to my CSS?

Tags: html, css

I looked at other people who asked this and nothing seemed to work. My HTML page can't find my CSS page although they are in the same folder. I am working in Dreamweaver but writing the code myself.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>home</title>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
<href="style.css"
type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="background"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
.background {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.98);
    background-image: url(images/me_atsunsetbackground.JPG);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Because you have a typo. It's supposed to be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />`. Your version has an extra `<` in front of `href`.

Answer (score 1):

do it like this :

```
<html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>home</title>
    <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="background"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="any_style_you_want.css">
</head>
```